# How to push a message on rabbitMQ to all consumers who subscribe to the topic queue, and confirm the consumption after all of them have received it

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

For example, there are now ten consumers subscribed to the topic exchange. I need to push a message. All ten consumers receive it and consume it only once, and then destroy the message. How can I do that? Only rabbitMQ!!

Comment: Do you want per consumer consuming whole messages of this topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the tutorial dedicated to how topic exchanges work: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-five-python.html

You can't guarantee that the consumers will consume the message "only once". Errors can cause re-deliveries among other things. It's rare but it can happen.

RabbitMQ does not provide any support for confirming that a number of consumers have received and processed a message. You will have to implement that yourself.